# Convert raw HTML codes to PDF File

Tags: html, css, spring, controller

I want to convert the raw html code to pdf file.
This is my Controller code

```
@RequestMapping("getpdf")
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response,String ref){


    OutputStream out = null;
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
    java.util.List items = null;

    ArticalBean abean=serviceLayer.getArtical(Integer.parseInt(ref));
        items = new ArrayList();
        items.add(abean.getArticle());             


    try {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
        document.open();
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Microweb Systems");
        document.add(paragraph);
        ListItem listItem;
        com.lowagie.text.List list = new com.lowagie.text.List(true, 15);
        Iterator i = items.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            listItem = new ListItem((String)i.next(), 
                    FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12));

            list.add(listItem);
        }
        document.add(list);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        document.close();
    }
    document.close();
}
```

It converts the HTML codes to PDF but that pdf also contains the tags

Like

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Is there is any way to remove these tags and show only Data.

I am providing the data from database via DTO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to remove the tags.

This can be done with `String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`.

For example `myString.replaceAll("^<[.]*>$" , "");` would remove any tags.
This, however, does not make the pdf look like the page does in a browser.